# Where is the opencv pack for mac os x?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I can't find the opencv pack for mac os x on opencv's website now. It looks so strange. And what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success to install it with homebrew
https://brew.sh/index_de.html

Comment: Once you have installed **homebrew**, you can run `brew options opencv` to find any options you desire, then run `brew install opencv <options>`.

Comment: Thanks very much!